# BigQuery SQL : Rolling count distinct bounded between two conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to find the rolling countdistinct of ip_var bounded between two events (in two different columns in Bigquery SQL).

eg i have a table of the form :

```
id  TIME_STAMP  event_1 event_2 ip_var
A   1               0   0         1
A   2               1   0         1
A   2               0   0         2
A   3               0   0         2
A   4               0   0         3
A   5               0   1         4
A   6               0   0         1
A   7               0   0         1
B   1               0   0         2
B   2               0   0         2
B   2               1   0         3
B   3               0   0         3
B   4               0   0         3
B   4               0   1         4
B   6               0   0         5
B   7               0   0         6
```

For each id , i need the countdistinct of ip_var when the event_1 happens till event_2 happens , its always guaranteed that even2 happens after event_1.

I have tried using rolling count for the problem without much success.

Final output looks like

```
id  bounded_count
A   2
B   1
```

Comment: not sure about your logic - i clearly count 4 distinct ip_var for A and 2 distinct for B. so are you excluding start and end of island from your logic? also you have duplicate time_stamp for both A and B, how you know in this case which one goes first . And finally - In your real table  - do you have just one pair of starts for event_1 and event_2 per id (as in your example)  or multiple?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant.Thanks .All great questions , regarding the duplicate_timestamps - There is no way of identifying which one should go first and so it can be a compromise here.Regarding he second question , there can be only just one pair per id as in the example. (But this question was very intriguing , and may be its something that . i can try out on a dummy dataset )

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant regarding the first question on excluding them , yes i am excluding them

Comment: got it - added my answer to the pile :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT ip_var) bounded_count
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    COUNTIF(event_1 = 1) OVER(win ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) grp,
    COUNTIF(event_1 = 1) OVER(win ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) != COUNTIF(event_2 = 1) OVER(win) qualify
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time_stamp)
)
WHERE qualify
GROUP BY id, grp
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row id  bounded_count 
1   A   2
2   B   1
```

Note: above solution also works in case if you have multiple qualified pairs, like in below example (same code, I just added more rows into sample data)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'A' id, 1 time_stamp, 0 event_1, 0 event_2, 1 ip_var UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 2, 1, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 2, 0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 3, 0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 4, 0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 5, 0, 1, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 6, 0, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 7, 0, 0, 1 UNION ALL

  SELECT 'A', 12, 1, 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 13, 0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 14, 0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 15, 0, 0, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 16, 0, 0, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 17, 0, 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 18, 0, 0, 1 UNION ALL

  SELECT 'B', 1, 0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 2, 0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 2, 1, 0, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 3, 0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 4, 0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 5, 0, 1, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 6, 0, 0, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 7, 0, 0, 6 
)
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT ip_var) bounded_count, grp
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    COUNTIF(event_1 = 1) OVER(win ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) grp,
    COUNTIF(event_1 = 1) OVER(win ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) != COUNTIF(event_2 = 1) OVER(win) qualify
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time_stamp)
)
WHERE qualify
GROUP BY id, grp
```

with result

```
Row id  bounded_count   grp  
1   A   2               1    
2   A   4               2    
3   B   1               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You can use window functions to calculate the timestamps for each event.  The rest is just filtering and aggregation:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT "A" as id, 1 as time_stamp, 0 as event_1, 0 as event_2, 1 as ip_var UNION ALL
      SELECT "A", 2,  1, 0, 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT "A", 2,  0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT "A", 3,  0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT "A", 4,  0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT "A", 5,  0, 1, 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT "A", 6,  0, 0, 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT "A", 7,  0, 0, 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT "B", 1,  0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT "B", 2,  0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT "B", 2,  1, 0, 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT "B", 3,  0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT "B", 4,  0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT "B", 4,  0, 1, 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT "B", 6,  0, 0, 5 UNION ALL
      SELECT "B", 7,  0, 0, 6
     )
select id, count(distinct ip_var) as bounded_count
from (select t.*,
             min(case when event_1 = 1 then time_stamp end) over (partition by id) as timestamp_1,
             max(case when event_2 = 1 then time_stamp end) over (partition by id) as timestamp_2
      from t
     ) t
where time_stamp > timestamp_1 and time_stamp < timestamp_2
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

1. Find out start_time and end_time for each ID
2. For each ID, filter out events that are not in counting window
3. Count distinct ip_var

In order to print out intermediate step, I used temp table to demonstrate the idea. You should make second temp table `id_start_end` a WITH clause to be more efficient.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE t as 
SELECT "A" id, 1 time_stamp, 0 event_1, 0 event_2, 1 ip_var UNION ALL
SELECT "A", 2,  1, 0, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT "A", 2,  0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT "A", 3,  0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT "A", 4,  0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT "A", 5,  0, 1, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT "A", 6,  0, 0, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT "A", 7,  0, 0, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT "B", 1,  0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT "B", 2,  0, 0, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT "B", 2,  1, 0, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT "B", 3,  0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT "B", 4,  0, 0, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT "B", 4,  0, 1, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT "B", 6,  0, 0, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT "B", 7,  0, 0, 6;

CREATE TEMP TABLE id_start_end AS
SELECT ids.id, t_start.time_stamp as start_time, t_end.time_stamp as end_time FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t) ids 
JOIN t AS t_start ON ids.id = t_start.id AND t_start.event_1 = 1
JOIN t AS t_end ON ids.id = t_end.id AND t_end.event_2 = 1;

SELECT * FROM id_start_end;

SELECT t.id, COUNT(DISTINCT ip_var)
FROM t JOIN id_start_end 
  ON t.id = id_start_end.id
    AND t.time_stamp < id_start_end.end_time
    AND t.time_stamp > id_start_end.start_time
GROUP BY t.id
```

Output table id_start_end:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | start_time | end_time |
+----+------------+----------+
| A  |          2 |        5 |
| B  |          2 |        4 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

Final output:

```
+----+-----+
| id | f0_ |
+----+-----+
| B  |   1 |
| A  |   2 |
+----+-----+
```